# Find index of first unsorted element in polars DataFrame

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe like below

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [3,2,1], "b":[3,4,5]})

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

I want to find the first index where the data is **not** sorted by (a, b). My dataframe is quite big so I want to do this in linear time (rather than calling sort). I tried creating a packed column and a shifted version of that like below

```py
df.with_columns(pl.struct("a", "b").alias("a_b")).with_columns(pl.col("a_b").shift().alias("shift_a_b"))

shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ a_b       ┆ shift_a_b   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---       ┆ ---         │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ struct[2] ┆ struct[2]   │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════╪═════════════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   ┆ {3,3}     ┆ {null,null} │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ {2,4}     ┆ {3,3}       │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ {1,5}     ┆ {2,4}       │
└─────┴─────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

Then I tried creating a mask to see if the elements were increasing

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col("a_b") < pl.col("shift_a_b"))
```

but this fails with the following Rust panic

```
df.with_columns(pl.struct("a", "b").alias("a_b")).with_columns(pl.col("a_b").shift().alias("shift_a_b")).with_columns(pl.col("a_b") < pl.col("shift_a_b"))

File ~/venvs/dev-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:7333, in DataFrame.with_columns(self, *exprs, **named_exprs)
   7185 def with_columns(
   7186     self,
   7187     *exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr],
   7188     **named_exprs: IntoExpr,
   7189 ) -> DataFrame:
   7190     """
   7191     Add columns to this DataFrame.
   7192 
   (...)
   7330 
   7331     """
   7332     return (
-> 7333         self.lazy()
   7334         .with_columns(*exprs, **named_exprs)
   7335         .collect(no_optimization=True)
   7336     )

File ~/venvs/dev-310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1531, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, no_optimization, slice_pushdown, common_subplan_elimination, streaming)
   1520     common_subplan_elimination = False
   1522 ldf = self._ldf.optimization_toggle(
   1523     type_coercion,
   1524     predicate_pushdown,
   (...)
   1529     streaming,
   1530 )
-> 1531 return wrap_df(ldf.collect())

PanicException: not implemented
```

I know that calling `.sort` on "a_b" works, so the elements must have a comparison defined on them, but I can't figure out how to tell polars that "a_b" and "shift_a_b" are comparable.

Answer (score 1):

So I think this can be solved with `.rank` actually

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"a": [3,2,1,3], "b":[3,4,5,3]})

shape: (4, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘

rank_df = (
    df.with_columns(pl.struct("a", "b").alias("a_b"))
    .select(pl.col("a_b"), pl.col("a_b").alias("rank").rank("min"))
    )

shape: (4, 2)
┌───────────┬──────┐
│ a_b       ┆ rank │
│ ---       ┆ ---  │
│ struct[2] ┆ u32  │
╞═══════════╪══════╡
│ {3,3}     ┆ 3    │
│ {2,4}     ┆ 2    │
│ {1,5}     ┆ 1    │
│ {3,3}     ┆ 3    │
└───────────┴──────┘
```

I can then just do a diff on the rank column and find the first instance not equal to null or 1

Comment: `I can then just do a diff on the rank column and find the first instance not equal to null or 1`---you'll want to look for the first negative value. With rank('min') if there are any rows with the same value, the rank of those will be the same and it'll skip however many positions as there are duplicates. For instance do `pl.DataFrame({"a": [3,2,1,1], "b":[3,4,5,5]}).with_columns(a_b=pl.struct('a','b')).with_columns(rank=pl.col('a_b').rank('min'))`